# No hotspot in a component created in Altium

Tags: components, altium, interconnect

I have added a component to an SCH library in Altium.

I have just drawn the component (just the schematic but not the footprint) and added to it a model that I found on the TI website. I just need the model because I just want to do a simulation (not a PCB.)

I think I have mapped the pins correctly but when I try to connect this component to my circuit, there is no hotspot when I connect the wire (no red cross indicating me that the connection is correct.)

I thought the problem may come from how I set the pins, but I don't really know how to solve this.

Comment: Did you put the pins the wrong way around? Go into your schematic component model and make sure the pins have little white crosshairs/dots on the ends where you intend to connect the wires. See this image: http://s32.postimg.org/m766j2v9x/crosshairs.png . It is not uncommon for beginners to accidentally place the pins backwards, with the crosshairs facing the inside of the component rather than facing outwards. See this image: http://s32.postimg.org/rb8irsted/crosshairs_bad.png

Comment: A picture is always helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I've just had something similar happen and found the electrical grid had been disabled. Go to Design/Document Options and check if the electrical grid is enabled. Mine wasn't and enabling it got me the hot spot back.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue with not having the hotspot. After enabling the Electrical Grid it is now showing the hotspot (red or blue cross on the pin). You can enable the Electric grid in the schematic by pressing "Shift + E" or you can go to "View > Grid > Toggle Electrical Grid" to enable or disable the grid.